# randomly select images using PIL

Tags: python, image, loops, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a folder with over 100k images, I am wondering how do I **use PIL to randomly select 5 images to display?**

The code below will return me all codes which is not feasible though.

```
from PIL import Image

path = '/Users/Desktop/folder'
image_list = []
for x in (path): 
    im = Image.open(image_filename)
    image_list.append(im)
images = np.array(images)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming that your path only consists of only image files*, in this case we can randomly select five different image files in a given directory and then open each of the image file using `PIL.Image` thereby appending them to the `image_list`.

Here is the code snippet which you might want to try:

```
import os
import random
from PIL import Image

path = '/Users/Desktop/folder'
image_list = []

names = random.choices(os.listdir(path), k=5) #----> Randomly select 5 images
for filename in names: 
    full_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(full_path):
        img = Image.open(full_path)
        image_list.append(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show a minimal example.

If image_list is all of your picture list,
then this maybe could solve your problem:

```
import random

RandomIndexList = [random.randint(0,range(len(image_list))) for i in range(5)] # 5 is the number of picture.
for i in RandomIndexList:
    image_list[i].show()
```